# Simple_form always sets pattern for email input element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I use simple_form to display an email field:

```
= f.simple_fields_for :user do |f|
 = f.input :email, wrapper: :append, pattern: false do
   = f.input_field :email, type: "email"
```

Somehow it always set's the pattern for the input field but I want to use the HTML5 validation of the email input field instead.

Is there a way to prevent simpleform from setting the pattern?

Answer (score 2):

You can monkey-patch SimpleForm:

```
module SimpleForm
  module Components
    module Pattern
      def pattern
        # Deactivated for good:
        #input_html_options[:pattern] ||= pattern_source
        nil
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now, pattern will no longer be generated from validations. You need to add pattern manually to each input that requires a pattern. Example:

```
= f.input :name, pattern: "[a-zA-Z]+"
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem ... found a workaround but its kind of hacky

add

```
:pattern => ".*"
```

to your field like this

```
<%= f.input_field :email, :autofocus => true, :pattern => ".*", :class => "span12", :placeholder => t('placeholder.email') %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather make a string_input.rb file in the app directory some where ... may be in a folder named 'inputs' then have this code

```
class StringInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::StringInput
  def input
    input_html_options[:class] = "input-xlarge #{input_html_options[:class]}"
    unless string?
     input_html_classes.unshift("string")
     input_html_options[:type] ||= input_type if html5?
    end
    input_html_options[:pattern] = nil

    add_size!
    @builder.text_field(attribute_name, input_html_options)
  end
end
```

This will have effect on all the pattern attributes so no need to put it in explicitly. of course you can also add a condition if the input type is email or not if you want to specify.

Happy coding :)